# How to get the first (oder last) n elements of a minizinc array with 1 dimension?

Tags: arrays, minizinc

Sounds quite straightforward, but I didn't find a solution yet.
How do I get the first (oder last) n elements of a minizinc array with one dimension? The result should be an array, so that I can apply count () oder sum().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if you have an array `arr` with an index set of `1..m` is the following array comprehension:

```
[ arr[i] | i in 1..n ]
```

You can also construct an array comprehension that does not depend on the index set starting from 1:

```
[ arr[i] | i in (min(index_set(arr)))..(min(index_set(arr)))+n ]
```

Note that either comprehension will not work if `length(arr) < n`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm.